# Delphi TAdoConnection Master/Detail : duplicate records in grid

Tags: delphi, adodb, tclientdataset

I made the following test for the problem. I have a `TAdoConnection` connected with an Access database with two tables (master/detail);

A `TADoDataset` with commandtext selecting the master table, a DatasetProvider conneced to the AdoDatset and a Clientdataset to the provider and a Datasource.

The same (4) components for the Detail set. On the main form two DBgrids.
Nothing special. But the one of the master records does not have  detail records.

When I scroll trough the master grid, after having selected the record without details, the details of the other masters are duplicated: a master with 3 details shows 6 and next time 9 etc.

This only happens with `TAdoDataset`, `DataProvider`, `Clientdataset`. When I use a `TSQLConnection` and a `TSQLDataset` the behaviour is normal. But in my current project I have to deal with `TAdoDataset`. Please help.

Comment: It sounds like an issue with the setup of the master/detail relations. Also, which Delphi version? There used to be an issue with ADO in Delphi 7.

Comment: Have you got the Master-Detail relationship defined between the two AdoDatasets or between the two ClientDatasets?

Comment: I use Delphi XE2.   The Master - Detail relationship is defined between the ClientDataset. (MasterSource property of the detail ClientDataset is set to the datasource of the master, MasterFields and IndexFieldNames are correct added).  I have experience with a dozen application where this correct works: but then I use a TSQLDataset in  stead of TAdoDataset and a TSQLConnection in stead of TAdoConnection.